# Why does my Bootstrap stretched link extend out several levels?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to stretched link for my nested div but it is including even parent. I need only listItem to be clickable but this makes entire card div clickable.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 mb-3 mt-2">
        <div class="card custom-bg-2 h-100">
          <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
            <h3 class="fw-bold text-white text-center">Page Title</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="listItem">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="rounded" alt="Title">
              <p><span class="badge bg-secondary text-light" style="font-size: large;">Title</span></p>
              <p><span class="badge bg-secondary ms-2">Views</span></p>
              <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-8 mb-3 mt-2">
          <div class="card custom-bg-2 h-100">
            <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
              <h3 class="fw-bold text-white">Category</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              ....
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/) (and the fundamental rules of [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)), stretched links apply to the nearest element *with non-static positioning*. You can put the `position-relative` class on the parent to make that so.

I've also replaced your inline font size styles with the `lead` class on the parent paragraph. Just don't use inline styles, especially when your style library provides [typography classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/) for that.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 mb-3 mt-2">
        <div class="card custom-bg-2 h-100">
          <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
            <h3 class="fw-bold text-white text-center">Page Title</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="listItem position-relative">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="rounded" alt="Title">
              <p class="lead"><span class="badge bg-secondary text-light">Title</span></p>
              <p><span class="badge bg-secondary ms-2">Views</span></p>
              <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-8 mb-3 mt-2">
          <div class="card custom-bg-2 h-100">
            <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
              <h3 class="fw-bold text-white">Category</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              ....
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```